# Wcf Service net.tcp calls failing

Tags: c#, wcf, net.tcp

I'm trying to set up some tests to see how WCF services work. I have code similar to this for basicHttp, netTcp, netPipe bindings calling a WCF service with those bindings.

```
using (_log = new StreamWriter(@"C:\TestRunnerLog.txt", true))
{
    var methodCallInformation = new MethodCallInformation { Method = NetPipeServiceCall, TotalTimeTakenForAllMethodCalls = new TimeSpan(), TotalNumberOfTimesMethodCalled = 0, TimesErrored = 0 };

    for (var i = 0; i < 25000; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            using(var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IChatHub>(new NetTcpBinding { Security = new NetTcpSecurity { Mode = SecurityMode.None } }, "net.tcp://localhost/test/test.svc"))
            {
                var channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
                await channel.GetPeople();
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            return stopwatch.Elapsed;

            methodCallInformation.TotalTimeTakenForAllMethodCalls += stopwatch.Elapsed;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            methodCallInformation.TimesErrored++;
        }

        methodCallInformation.TotalNumberOfTimesMethodCalled++;
    }

    await _log.WriteLineAsync(string.Format("net.tcp:\tTimesCalled:{0}\tTotalTime:{1}\tAverageTime:{2}\tErrors:{3}", methodCallInformation.TotalNumberOfTimesMethodCalled, methodCallInformation.TotalTimeTakenForAllMethodCalls, new TimeSpan(methodCallInformation.TotalTimeTakenForAllMethodCalls.Ticks / methodCallInformation.TotalNumberOfTimesMethodCalled), methodCallInformation.TimesErrored));
}
```

I'm confused by the results I'm getting though. I'm running all iterations locally and have the service and client all running locally on my machine. Based on my research, netPipe should be the fastest, followed by netTcp and then basicHttp. The code I have randomizes these calls instead of the each loop only calling one binding for all iterations as in the sample above.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http:       TimesCalled:24981   TotalTime:00:00:46.0452454  AverageTime:00:00:00.0018432    Errors:0
net.tcp:    TimesCalled:25168   TotalTime:00:00:16.7776697  AverageTime:00:00:00.0006666    Errors:17593
net.pipe:   TimesCalled:24786   TotalTime:00:00:50.5698790  AverageTime:00:00:00.0020402    Errors:0
```

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing incorrectly to get all of those errors with net.tcp and why the timing seems to be so slow for net.pipe.

Here are the bindings I've set up on the service:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpDefaultBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpDefaultBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                <message clientCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
    <netNamedPipeBinding>
        <binding name="netNamedPipeDefaultBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <security mode="None">
            </security>
        </binding>
    </netNamedPipeBinding>
</bindings>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please give feedback. Why the down vote?

Comment: you haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't apparent, but I did have this in the post: I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing incorrectly to get all of those errors with net.tcp and why the timing seems to be so slow for net.pipe.

To add to that. Am I not properly creating connections or disposing of them? Why would I be seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Your NetTcp test is likely completing so much faster due to the fact that it is throwing an exception ~17,000 out of ~25,000 times.  You are more or less just testing how fast your application can throw exceptions.

Running locally, the differences between the bindings are going to be almost imperceptible and environmental factors will likely be enough to skew your results.  Over a network the results may be different, primarily due to message encoding (binary vs. text with binary being more efficient).  That hopefully answers your question of why Named Pipes are "slow" in comparison to NetTcp.

Secondly, to determine why NetTcp is failing, you need to stop hiding the exception.

```
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // you should also be reporting your exception somewhere here...
        methodCallInformation.TimesErrored++;   

    }
```

Or just set Visual Studio to break on all exceptions and run in debug mode.  Speculating why something might be producing an error, in my experience, is generally not a good way to troubleshoot a problem.  It is a method that should be reserved only when there are no other options available.  If you provide the exception details, we can likely provide more insight.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try to collect some exception information. I started with a small number of iterations and kept increasing it. ~7500 calls gave no errors for tcp, but once I started ~10000 is when the errors began and is why I suspected improper disposal. As far as I can tell, all three use http protocol and pipe is supposed to be the fastest on a single box, tcp is supposed to perform better on the network and http for cross networks. It makes sense that I would see degrading performance if I moved the service to another box, but this is the peak for all of them?